# Calling the over-riding function in the parent class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have a little question about java inheritance. So say I have the following classes.

```
class ScreenObject {
    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) {
        Input input = gc.getInput();
        int mouseX = input.getMouseX();
        int mouseY = input.getMouseY();
        boolean mouseClick = input.isMouseButtonDown(Input.MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON);
        if (detectMouseClick(mouseX, mouseY, mouseClick)) {
        this.performClick(gc,sbg,delta);
        }
    }


    public void performClick(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) {
    }
}

class CrewMember extends ScreenObject {
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) {
    super.update(gc, sbg, delta);
    }

    public void performClick(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

Now when `crewMember.update()` is called with the right arguments, there is no output, when there should be "hi".

Comment: Please provide some context. Are you referring to a Foo, or a Bar?

Comment: Have you actually **tried** it? In Java, all methods are virtual, therefore `Bar.g()` will actually call `Bar.f()`.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I have tried it, but there is probably a bug somewhere that I missed. I tried looking it up, but only found references to calling the super function, so I figured that it is uncommon. But I guess it's really the other way round.

Comment: Then what did you try? Invoke the `Bar.f()` method in an instance of `Foo`? That is only possible for `static` methods (these are not `virtual`).

Comment: I did not invoke Bar.f(), which would not work since as you said, it is not static. I guess I should provide more context. I'll update the code.

Comment: Try providing actual output and expected output.

Comment: No, it *doesn't* trigger Foo's f(), I get the expected output, 'Bye.'

Comment: Well it's in the context of a game using Slick2D, but I guess I'll get rid of the unnecessary methods. Just for the record, I understand the difference between static and non-static methods. But thanks for explaining anyway.

Comment: @user2350018 The context doesn't matter; this is basic Java. It's far more likely you're either not running the code you think you are, or the methods don't do what you think they do, or you're not instantiating what you think you are, etc. The code above works as Java is supposed to and outputs `Bye.`.

Comment: I guess I'll just go back to staring at it.

Comment: @user2350018 Are you sure you actually have a CrewMember? I think there's something wrong in your assumptions, because Java works (in general). Consider using a debugger.

Comment: Actually, will casting it to the parent class affect it? Now that I think about it, it is called from an ArrayList of values of the parent class.

Comment: Casting will not matter.

Comment: @user2350018 Not only does casting not matter, you could say `Foo b = new Bar()` and still get the expected `Bye.` output.

Comment: Nevermind. It's all working now. And the issue is even more fundamental. For some reason Eclipse did not recompile my changes. I added a method, ran it, and removed the method without making any other changes. It all worked when I tried to run it again. Sorry to have wasted everyone's time.

Comment: That's the "not running the code you think you are" one :) It happens.

Comment: @user2350018: a little bit of banging your head against the wall is just part of the fun.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a Bar, then when you call f() on it, even if you call it from Foo code, you get Bar's f. There's no choice, if it's overridden you get the overridden one, so calling

```
new Bar().g();
```

will result in "bye" getting written to the console.

Overriding methods called in the superclass is a good way to extend a class's functionality, where you know a class should always do something but the details vary per subclass. It's common to make a superclass method abstract so the subclasses have to implement it, but if there's a reasonable default you could add that to the superclass.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding an example to help OP to understand @Nathan Hughes's description:

```
Foo one = new Foo();
one.f(); // Foo.f() is called

Foo two = new Bar();
two.f(); // Bar.f() is called

Bar three = new Bar();
three.f(); // Bar.f() is called
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, all non-static methods are "virtual". This means that any call to `f()` will use the overridden version of the current *instance*. You can call the super class method using `super.f();`, but you cannot call *down* into a subclass.

This means that the code

```
public void g() {
    f();
}
```

is: "invoke the method `f()` of the *current instance*. If the current instance if of type `Bar`, this *will* invoke the function `Bar.f()`.

This does not apply to `static` functions (except that you will probably run into compilation problems because of cyclic dependencies).

If you make your methods `static`, a third class can actually call:

```
Foo.f();
Bar.f();
```

Note that there are *no instances* here, but these are class methods.